# What is this fossil?

Tags: fossils

While walking in a state park yesterday in the Chattanooga, TN area we came across a rock that looked like this. Is it some kind of holdfast or washout from cement work? (There is an old reservoir nearby.) The rock layers in the area are Pennsylvanian.

[image]

[image]

Comment: To those that voted to close Fossil identification is considered on-topic, please don't vote to close fossils are not the same as rocks.

Comment: @John is what we see in the pictures a fossil or only a strange shape in the rock,what type of rock is it and what is the size of the object some more information had been nice.

Comment: @trondhansen scale would be nice but otherwise it is a very good fossil identification question, the type of rock is not actually that helpful for fossils. the location and age is given which is more than most can give. there is a guide for fossil questions you can check that points out most of the information for identifying rocks is actually useless for fossils.

Comment: I initiated a meta thread about this question [here](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1873/6016).